# Email and SMS queuing in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, sms-gateway

I am developing a node.js app. In my app, I need to send blast emails and SMS to users satisfying a particular criteria. I use Gmail SMTP for emails and a third party vendor for SMS. I'm assuming firing the API's for email and sms services in a loop is dangerous. What's the right way do it?

Comment: Why you think, thats it's dangerous?

Comment: I've heard scary stories of emails and SMS's not being delivered. Just wanted to confirm before pushing it into production.

Comment: It's depends on a lot of things, main point - is exactly which kind of services you're using. Not possible to answer your question how it looks now.

Comment: The whole idea is, when an API submits data, a blast email and sms should be sent to ~50k-1 million users. However the API doesn't have to wait until the notifications are sent. On success of data submission, a true response is returned. Currently I'm running on an AWS small instance, with MySQL RDS. (The servers will be scaled as the user base increases)

Comment: You should use dedicated service like [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) or [SendGrid](http://mbsy.co/sendgrid/12237825) for emails (they have [NodeMailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) plugins) and something similar for SMS that assures you it can handle bulk queues.

Answer (score 1):

The time spent is obviously proportional to N, being N the size of your set. As much users you have, longer it takes. Keep in mind that requests over the network are not blocking in any case.

Anyway, unless it risks N to be thousands or millions of items, you can do it in a loop and attach a proper callback to handle responses/errors.

Otherwise, you can send an email/sms and schedule the same operation for the next element using `nextTick` (see nodejs documentation for further details).
This way you'll spread all the activities over several iterations of the event loop.

Comment: I've written an API which submits data. When this event occurs, blast emails and sms's are sent to the users. However, API will return the response before the emails and sms's are completely sent. The emails and SMS are just confirmation emails and doesn't put the users in risks. Do you think I can still proceed with this implementation?

Comment: I guess the response object you receive is an object that emits events like `data` or `error`, isn't? If this is the case, attach a couple of listeners on those events because you are entering the async world, then you can freely proceed for those operations are not blocking ones.

Comment: I have seen people tracking status of the emails and sms sent, and running a crone job to ensure the notifications are delivered. That according to me, is putting extra load on the server. Running a crone job through a million users is not a joke. That's what confused me.

Comment: So, define the size of your set. When you start sending a mail, do you iterate over millions of users? What's the exact process you expect to have? Do you read data and store response on a db? We need more details about the problem and the expectations to give you more details about a possible solution.

Comment: As a mobile user, I create a request for a service by calling a create request API in the backend. I have a set of service providers who are registered with the app. Service providers who fall under a certain criteria to serve the request, get notified by emails and sms. Currently, I have 50,000 service providers.

Comment: How is the response object you receive defined? Does it return data by means of an async layer (as an example, using events)? It's quite difficult without knowing which library you are using, the definition of the api, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kue npm library for creating queue of your email or sms tasks it runs parallels.
https://medium.com/@techsuneel99/how-to-send-50000-emails-at-once-in-queue-node-js-b633ef9b3b30

Comment: So it's all about using SendGrid actually, not sure if you really need kue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.